# Laravel Query Builder bindings

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Can someone please explain why in Laravel the first code works while the second one doesn't work.

```
$data = DB::select("SELECT * FROM people WHERE name LIKE '%john%'");


$data = DB::select("SELECT * FROM people WHERE name LIKE '?'", ['%john%']);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you what to use Query Builder you can do this:

```
$data = DB::select("SELECT * FROM people WHERE name LIKE :name", ['name' => "%john%"]);
```

But it is better to use Eloquent:

```
People::where('name', 'like', "%john%")->get();
```

Comment: When I try to call the where method directly from my People model I can't seem to find it.

Comment: Does your model extends ```Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model``` ?

Comment: Yes, all my models extend from Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model

Comment: What error are you getting when calling ```where``` method on People model?

Comment: Oh, my bad! While it isn't being suggested by the editor I'm using, it does seem to be working fine!